# Java HTTP Live Stream segmenter

Tags: iphone, streaming, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

A few months ago when I looked into HTTP-live streaming I thought I found a Java Library which can act as the segmenter to create a HTTP Live Stream. However, I cannot find it back. Is there anybody who knows about a way to directly segment the files?

Or, with iOS 5, if there are any libraries yet which can create the m3u8 files from a set of encoded files without physical file segmentation?

I have a server running the (Java) Play Framework and will use FFMPEG (possibly in a Java wrapper) to encode and now look for something to create the playlist files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working with Xuggler at the moment, and have a segmenter and encoder working,must the .m3u8 file is not accepted by iOS devices so some work needs to be done, but it has the promise to be successfull.